# How to create a JSON

Tags: android, json, arrays

I was create a `JSON Object` like below but i don't know how can fill parameters field with JSONStringer? And parameters field is a `JSONArray` or `Array String`?

```
{"name":"Katy", "parameters":["JAK","1999"], "Age":25}
```

Thanks for your help .

Comment: Where does the JSON data come from? Is it hardcoded in your program? Are you reading it from a file? Are you making a HTTP request and getting this as a response?

Comment: make it be clearer !! what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Code-Apprentice, i want to create a json for send to a web service. Where is hard coded? Can i use another way for create this json for send to web service? Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below

```
String mParameters[] = { "JAK", "1999" };

        JSONObject mJson = new JSONObject();
        try {
            mJson.put("name", "Katy");
            JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(mParameters));
            mJson.putOpt("parameters", mJSONArray);
            mJson.put("Age", 25);
            System.out.println("JSon::"+ mJson.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation for JSON](http://json.org/) will show you that an easy way to distinguish wheter your JSON string is an array is whether it starts with a `[`, so "parameters" in your example is a `JSONArray`.

Without knowing how you will be getting the data you want to put in your object, here is an example of how you would populate it (assuming you have an array of `JAKS` to insert).

```
                    JSONObject yourObject = new JSONObject();
                    String[] JAKS = {"1999", "2000", "2001"};
                    JSONArray paramaters = new JSONArray();
                    try {
                        yourObject.put("name", "Katy");
                        for (String JAK : JAKS) {
                            JSONObject yourParamater = new JSONObject();
                            yourParamater.put("JAK", JAK);
                            paramaters.put(yourParamater);
                        }
                        yourObject.put("parameters", paramaters);
                        yourObject.put("Age", 25);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
//other imports
//...

try {
    //Create the JSON Object
    JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject();
    String parameters[] = new String[]{"JAK","1999"};
    //use the method put to "fill" the values
    myObject.put("name", "Katy");
    myObject.put("parameter",(Object)parameters);
    myObject.put("age", 25);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
try{
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
   jsonObject.put("name","Katy");
   jsonObject.put("parameters",new String[]{"JAK","1999"});
   jsonObject.put("Age","25");
}catch (Throwable e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```